# Where can I find the specific power output of a specific NDB?

Tags: radio-navigation

As a rule of thumb I can get an approximate range of an NDB with the formulae:
Over sea: range=3SQRT Power
Over land: range=2SQRT Power 
To use this formula I need to find out what Power has the NDB that I need to use; Where should I look to find out?

Comment: For what it's worth, you have a first indication of the power by looking at [the NDB class](http://www.pilotnav.com/navaid/faa-2073#FAANavaidClassDesignatorExplanation) (e.g. MH is less than 50 W and usable within 25 NM at all altitudes). Note that the power which must be taken into account is the effective isotropic radiated power ([EIRP](https://www.air-stream.org/technical-references/effective-isotropic-radiated-power-eirp)), which depends on the antenna gain.

Comment: @mins  Well it's a start. But I was wandering if there is a list of NDB specifications somewhere on AIP or elsewhere open for the pubblic to use.

Comment: I'm not even sure if the US has more than 10 NDB's left, and I would bet some of those are long dead. I don't remember the last modern aircraft I've seen equipped with an ADF. Then again, there's plenty of AM radio stations in the US and many of them are operating in the 50 kW power range. I remember getting in trouble as a student pilot on my long XC because of weather, and using the NDB in Puerto Rico to make sure I was still on course, 'cause I couldn't see the shoreline and I was worried. Very worried. LOL!